# Sets defined by distance to a convex set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, convex-analysis

Let $Y \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a bounded convex set, let $R>0$, and let $$Z := \left\{z \in \mathbb R^n : d(z,Y) > \dfrac12R \right\}$$

where

$$
d(z,Y) = \inf_{y\in Y}|y-z|.
$$

If you like, you may replace $Y$ by its closure so that we can be sure it is compact, and that the infimum above is actually a minimum. You may also assume that the diameter of $Y$ is less than $\dfrac R2$ (I don't think this will be directly useful, but it does happen to be true in the case I'm considering).

Now, is it true that:

> If $x \in Y^c \cap Z^c$, then $d(x,Z) \leq R$ ?

Intuitively, this is "obvious" e.g. if $Y$ is a disc, then $Y^c \cap Z^c$ is an annulus of 'width' $\dfrac R2$, and so it's clearly impossible for $B_x(R) \subset Z^c$.

Further, it is clear that convexity is required: if $Y$ is itself an annulus, with inner radius, say, $R/4$ and outer radius $2R$, then this obviously fails (take $x$ to be in the "hole" of the annulus).

Finally, if all this holds in $\mathbb R^n$, is it also true in a more general setting? I.e. if $Y \subset M$ is a bounded and (geodesically) convex subset of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$?

Comment: I think that the answer is yes. The points farthest away from $Z$ are those that are close to the boundary of $Y$, and if $d(x,Y)=\epsilon$ then $B_x(R)$ will contain a point $y$ such that $d(y,Z^c)=\epsilon$ so $y\in Z$ and $d(x,Z)\leq R$.

Comment: I think all that you can claim is "$B_x(R)$ will contain a point $y$ such that $d(y,Z^c) \leq \epsilon$" (because, indeed, such a $y$ might well be in $Y$, and so in $Z^c$ as well)

Comment: The point $y\in Z$ to which I am referring to is lying on the line determined by $x$ and a point closest to it in $Y$ (that is, a point with distance $\epsilon$ from $x$).

Comment: To put another way: for a point $x$ outside of $Y$, that is, $d(x,Y)=\epsilon>0$, there must be a point $y\in Z$ at distance at most $\frac{R}{2}$ from $x$, because otherwise $x\in Y$ since $Y=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n | d(x,Z)>\frac{R}{2}\}$ in this case.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see how $Y = \{x \in \mathbb R^n : d(x,Z) > \frac R2\}$ follows. In the case of a non-convex $Y$ this will be false; if it follows in the convex case, it isn't obvious to me how. (and thanks for taking the time for your replies!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Let's first consider the case when $Y$ is closed. Let $P\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to Y$ be the projecion, i.e. $d(x,P(x)) = d(x,Y)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

For $p\in Y^c\cap Z^c$, $Y$ lies entirely on one side of the hyperplane $$H = \{ x : \langle p-P(p), x-P(p)\rangle = 0\},$$ and $p$ lies on the other side, so we have, writing $y_p = P(p)$,

$$P(y_p + t(p-y_p)) = y_p$$

for all $t > 0$. For all $t > c = \frac{R}{2\lVert p-y_p\rVert}$, we have $z(t) = y_p + t(p-y_p) \in Z$, since $d(z(t),Y) = \lVert z(t)-y_p\rVert = t\lVert p-y_p\rVert$, and $\lVert z(t)-p\rVert = (t-1)\lVert p-y_p\rVert \xrightarrow{t\to c} \frac{R}{2}-\lVert p-y_p\rVert < R$.

In fact, we have $d(p,Z) \leqslant \frac{R}{2}$.

If $Y$ is not closed, we note that for every point $x$ we have $d(x,Y) = d(x,\overline{Y})$, hence both convex set determine the same $Z$, and for the boundary points of $Y$, the inequality follows by continuity since it holds on $\overline{Y}^c \cap Z^c$.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. Do you have any sense of whether this translates to the case of a Riemannian manifold? (in particular, do the projection and hyperplane constructions still work?)

Comment: I don't know enough differential geometry to be sure, but I would expect that for small enough $R$, points on the same geodesic will have the same closest point in $\overline{Y}$ at least until some way into $Z$. Then the same argument works. If $R$ is too large, the closest point might jump before $Z$ is reached, and then the inequality might not hold.

Comment: Alright, thanks again.